# How can i completly restart my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

When my app loses the Internet I want to display a screen that says "no internet". Until here it works. But my webview doesn't reload. Because that I want to completly restart my app when I click on the reconnect button.
I tried to make that with the Phoenix package but it doesn't work.
Does anyone know what i did wrong? Or has anyone a better solution?
Here my source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phoenix/flutter_phoenix.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Phoenix(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Herospace(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
  ),);
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
}

class Herospace extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HerospaceState createState() => _HerospaceState();
}

class _HerospaceState extends State<Herospace> {
  final keyIsFirstLoaded = 'is_first_loaded';

  

  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  var connectionStatus = false;

  Future<bool> check() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      setState(() {
        connectionStatus = true;
      });
    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      setState(() {
        connectionStatus = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        connectionStatus = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: check(), // a previously-obtained Future or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if (connectionStatus == true) {
            //if Internet is connected
            return SafeArea(
              bottom: false,
              left: false,
              right: false,
              child: Scaffold(
                body: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://herospace.ch',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                ),
                floatingActionButton:
                    NavigationControls(_controller.future), // <-- added this
              ),
            );
          } else {
            //If internet is not connected
            return Scaffold(
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/noWifi.png', height: 250),
                    Text(
                      "Ou, du brauchst Internet um diese App zu nutzen. Bitte schalte es an.",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: const Text('Restart'),
                  onPressed: () => Phoenix.rebirth(context),
                ),
                    
                    Text(
                      "Bitte aktiviere das Internet und starte die App erneut.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) plugin. It can restart the whole app with a single function call by using **native APIs**.

```
onPressed: () {
  Restart.restartApp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know `connectivity` package has a stream which takes events when connection status is changed. So try to wrap your `SafeArea` with `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder`. So the `StreamBuilder` will updates the child each time when connection state is changed.